# a bar showing ratios of content

Tags: android, layout

i have a bar in my app as shown below, as it clearly shows each material has a color and each color takes from the bar in relation to its quantity.... but i have made this in a very primitive way.

i did some research and found that there are libraries for pie charts.... i was wondering if there are libraries for bars similar like the one i attached in android.

i have tried using stacked bar charts and using only one bar but failed

[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ6VJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mpChart library.
add this library to your project.

```
  implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'
```

Comment: would you provide some kind of tutorial link for it?

Comment: here is the githiub link  https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart they have mentioned below